# putting sing up with google button in android app and getting all details of logged in user like username, email, dob, profile picture etc

Tags: android

I have used the code from below link works good but i need to access user's dob, gender, etc

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

I updated the `getProfileInformation()` like,so please help. but i am not getting details like gender, dob, location, etc.

```
/**
 * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
 * */
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

            System.out.println("mGoogleApiClietn: "
                    + mGoogleApiClient.toString());

            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            String dob = currentPerson.getBirthday();
            int gender = currentPerson.getGender();
            String aboutme = currentPerson.getAboutMe();
            String location = currentPerson.getCurrentLocation();
            int s = currentPerson.getRelationshipStatus();

            System.out.println("person name: " + personName);

            System.out.println("person photo url: " + personPhotoUrl);

            System.out.println("person email: " + email);

            System.out.println("person google plus profile url: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile);
            System.out.println("person DOB: " + dob);
            System.out.println("person Gender: " + gender);
            System.out.println("person About me: " + aboutme);
            System.out.println("person Location: " + location);
            System.out.println("person Relationship Status: " + s);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);
            txtdetail.setText("Dob: " + dob + "\nGender: " + gender
                    + "\nabout me:" + "\nLocation:" + location);

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl,
                    personName);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/22/android-login-using-google/